# Code a different structure in css

Tags: css, structure

The image:

[image]

I want to code this image!

A simple code: (with problem)

```
.hr{
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  background : #ddd;
  clear both;
  margin-top: 100px ;
}
.vr{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:900px;
  background : #000;
  top:-300px;
  z-index:-1
}


<div class='hr' style=''><div class='vr' style='left:100px;'></div><div class='vr' style='right:100px;z-index:0'></div></div>
<div class='hr' style=''></div>
```

..............

Comment: Not possible with this HTML structure, you'll need to cut a horizontal element in two pieces with separate z-index.

Comment: Or you can make use of **pseudo selectors**?

Comment: pseudo selectors ? do you mean after , before ?

Comment: @danialdezfooli https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Comment: @danialdezfooli I'm late but I answered too. :)

Comment: so tanx :) now im sure for this subject : )

Comment: Can you see this topic ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764944/wordpress-network-subdomains-returns-404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a hack using pseudo elements this way -

```css
.hr{
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  background : #ddd;
  clear both;
  margin-top: 100px ;
}
.vr{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:900px;
  background : #000;
  top:-300px;
  z-index:-1
}

.bottom:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='hr' style=''>
  <div class='vr' style='left:100px;'></div>
  <div class='vr' style='right:100px;z-index:0'></div>
</div>
<div class='hr bottom' style=''></div>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pseudo-selector". I guess you mean "pseudo-element".

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOvNdK

I created 4 `div` elements in the `LBRT` order: the first element (the left vertical bar) overlaps the last one (the top horizontal bar) in the *top-left* cross thanks to a `:before` pseudoelement applied to the left vertical bar.

All the sizes and offsets are in relative units, so you could easily scale up (or down) the whole draw simply changing the size of the parent element.

**Markup**

```
<div class="draw">
  <div class="v1"></div>
  <div class="h2"></div>
  <div class="v2"></div>
  <div class="h1"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.draw { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px #ccc dashed;
}

.draw div { position: absolute; }

.draw div[class^="h"] {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #d8d8d8;
}

.draw div[class^="v"] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  top: 0;
  background: #212121;
}

.draw .h1 { top : 20%; }
.draw .h2 { top : 60%; }
.draw .v1 { left : 20%; }
.draw .v2 { left : 60%; }

.draw .v1:before { 
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  content: "";
  background: inherit;
}
```

---

**Result**

[image]